# How do I get information from a List Item onClick?

Tags: android

I am using a listView that is being populated from a database. I know that I can use the onClick listener to get the position. But once I have the position how do I get further information? For instance, if there is a name textView in the list item, how do I get that?

```
  <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textName" android:layout_weight=".65" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="16sp" android:text="Item Label" android:layout_width="0sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginLeft="10px"></TextView>
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textTime" android:layout_width="0sp" android:layout_weight=".35" android:text="Time" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right" android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginRight="10px"></TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textAddress" android:text="address" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="30sp" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textAddress"  android:text="" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textAddress" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textAddress" android:id="@+id/textCross" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the `id` or the `view` parameter passed into the onClick listener:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

**Using `id`:**
Do a database call with the id as a where parameter.

**Using `view`:**
Find the child view (the `TextView` you mention in your question) and call `getText()` on it.

Comment: You can also get a cursor that holds the info at that position doing: `Cursor d = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: Ok, if I use the view, position, or id. How can I access the name view in this case (added above). I am not getting how I can access the nested Textviews.